# Select a Node at Random from Unbalanced Binary Tree

Tags: algorithm, recursion, binary-tree

One of my friends had the following interview question, and neither of us are quite sure what the correct answer is. Does anyone have an idea about how to approach this?

> Given an unbalanced binary tree, describe an algorithm to select a node at random such  that each node has an equal probability of being selected.

Comment: I would strike the "most efficient" part of this question to begin with. If not, then I wonder what kind of efficiency you're talking about. Speed? Memory?

Comment: Please show your attempt.

Comment: By efficiency I was mostly referring to speed. I think it should be possible to do it one pass through the tree, but maybe it's not. It would be super easy to do this in O(n) time where you just go through and count the number of nodes, then randomly select a number between 1 and n, then go to that node

Comment: 1) Do you know the tree size in advance? 2) are you allowed to alter the tree ? 3) can you use additional memory ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do it with a single pass of the tree. The algorithm is the same as with a list.

When you see the first item in the tree, you set it as the selected item.

When you see the second item, you pick a random number in the range (0,2]. If it's 1, then the new item becomes the selected item. Otherwise you skip that item.

For each node you see, you increase the count, and with probability 1/count, you select it. So at the 101st node, you pick a random number in the range (0,101]. If it's 100, that node is the new selected node.

When you're done traversing the tree, return the selected node. The operation is O(n) in time, with n being the number of nodes in the tree, and O(1) in space. No preprocessing required.

Comment: Wow that's super clever. I really like this. I'm going to assume that this is the best solution because you need to know practically zero information beforehand and only takes one pass through the tree.

Comment: @Jim Mischel `If it's 100, that node is the new selected node`. As the number of nodes `increases` , the probability for them being selected `decreases` . so best chance of selection is for nodes `1 , 2, 3 .. ` , not for `20 , 21 , .......` . `each node will not have equal probability of being selected.` Please clarify , i have trouble understanding it .

Comment: @Jim Mischel  may be it should be modified to : if we are at node X , generate a random number between (0 , X ] , `if number > X/2` select node X , else don't .

Comment: @aseem: No, the way I stated it is correct. For example with 2 nodes you select the first item. Then when you see the second item you *replace* the first item with probability 1/2. When you see the third item, you replace the selected item with probability 1/3. Every item has equal probability of being the selected item.

Comment: This is essentially reservoir sampling.

Comment: I don't think this works... when I try it on paper it seems to give a significant bias to the first node

Comment: @KernelDeimos It's called reservoir sampling. If you're seeing a significant bias then I suspect you're doing something wrong in your implementation. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling

Comment: @JimMischel my implementation was paper and a random number generator... but you're right, I just got a biased-looking result a couple times by total fluke

Answer (score 1):

We can do this recursively in one parse by selecting the random node while parsing the tree and counting the number of nodes in left and right sub tree. At every step in recursion, we return the number of nodes at the root and a random node selected uniformly randomly from nodes in sub tree rooted at root.

Let's say number of nodes in left sub tree is n_l and number of nodes in right sub tree is `n_r`. Also, randomly selected node from left and right subtree be `R_l` and `R_r` respectively. Then, select a uniform random number in [0,1] and select `R_l` with probability `n_l/(n_l+n_r+1)` or select root with probability `1/(n_l+n_r+1)` or select `R_r` with probability `n_r/(n_l+n_r+1)`.

Answer (score 0):

### Note

If you're only doing a single query, and you don't already have a count at each node, the best time complexity you can get is `O(n)`, so the depth-first-search approach would be the best one.

For repeated queries, the best option depends on the given constraints
(the fastest per-query approach is using a supplementary array).

### Supplementary array

**`O(n)` space, `O(n)` preprocessing, `O(1)` insert / remove, `O(1)` query**

Have a supplementary array containing all the nodes.

Also have each node store its own index (so you can remove it from the array in O(1) - the way to do this would be to swap it with the last element in the array, update the index of the node that was at the last index appropriately and decrease the size of the array (removing the last element).

To get a random node, simply generate a random index in the array.

### Per-node count

**Modified tree (`O(n)` space), N/A (or `O(n)`) preprocessing, `O(depth)` insert / remove, `O(depth)` query**

Let each node contain the number of elements in its subtree.

When generating a random node, go left or right based on the value of a random number generated and the counts of the left or right subtrees.

```
// note that subtreeCount = leftCount + rightCount + 1
val = getRandomNumber(subtreeCount)
if val = 0
  return this node
else if val <= leftCount
  go left
else
  go right
```

### Depth-first-search

**`O(depth)` space, `O(1)` preprocessing, `O(1)` insert / remove, `O(n)` query**

Count the number of nodes in the tree (if you don't already have the count).

Generate a random number between 0 and the number of nodes.

Simply do a depth-first-search through the tree and stop when you've processed the desired number of nodes.

This presumes a node doesn't have a `parent` member - having this will make this `O(1)` space.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented @jim-mischel's algorithm in C# and it works great:

```
private void SelectRandomNode(ref int count, Node curNode, ref Node selectedNode)
{
    foreach( var childNode in curNode.Children )
    {
        ++count;

        if( random.Next(count) == count - 1 )
            selectedNode = childNode;

        SelectRandomNode(ref count, childNode, ref selectedNode);
    }
}
```

Call it like this:

```
var count = 1;
Node selected = root;
SelectRandomNode(ref count, root, ref selected);
```