# Genetic Operators on Binary Tree

Tags: java, tree, binary-tree, genetic-algorithm, mutation

I am having problems trying to wrap my head around applying genetic operators to binary trees.

Firstly I have methods that generate two types of trees for the initial population, namely **Grow** (tree of variable size) and **Full** (balanced same shape and size tree).

```
    FULL                        GROW
     (*)                         (*)  
  (+)   (-)                   (5)   (-)
(1)(2) (3)(4)                     (6) (7)
```

The class for each tree looks like this:

```
public class Tree<E>{

   E element;
   Tree<E> left, right;
   double rawFit;
   int hitRat;

   public Tree(E element)
   {
      this.element=element;
   }   

   public Tree (E element, Tree left, Tree right) 
   {
      this.element = element;
      this.left = left;
      this.right = right;
       }

        //MORE
        //CODE
}
```

Now this is where I am having troubles understanding how to implement genetic operators, namely **Mutation** and **Crossover**

Randomly selecting a tree from my initial population, how do I go about applying theses genetic operators? 
For **Mutation**:

- I need to randomly select a point in a parent tree.
- Remove the entire subtree below that selected point.
- Generate a new subtree of similar depth to the removed subtree.
- Replace it back on the original parent tree and the selected point.

This is now the offspring.

Graphic Depiction:

```
                             PARENT
                              (*)            
randomly chosen point -->  (+)   (-)  
                         (1)(2) (3)(4)

       OFFSPRING         RANDOM SUBTREE
         (*)            
    (NULL)  (-)     +        (*) 
          (3) (4)          (5) (6)

     NEW OFFSPRING
          (*)            
      (*)    (-) 
    (5)(6) (3) (4)
```

I also need to do something similar for Crossover as well.

It seems easy in theory, but I have no idea how to code this (Java). Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT:** The method I've used for generating a full tree looks like this:

```
private static final String[] OPERATORS = {"+", "-", "/", "*"};
private static final int MAX_OPERAND = 100;
public static Tree full(int depth) {
        if (depth > 1) {
            String operator = OPERATORS[random.nextInt(OPERATORS.length)];
            return new Tree(operator, full(depth - 1), full(depth - 1));
        } else {
            return new Tree(random.nextInt(MAX_OPERAND) + 1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What have you done so far? Also how you want to generate the "Generate a new subtree of similar depth to the removed subtree." ?

Comment: @StefanSprenger I've edited my question to show how I've created a tree. The same method can be used to generate a subtree.

Answer (score 2):

I'll try and explain some of the steps in brief.

### Randomly select a point in a parent tree

One way of doing this would be to choose a random number, say `k`, between 0 and the number of non-leaf elements in the tree. The random point would be the `k`th element while [traversing the tree in order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#In-order_.28symmetric.29).

### Replace the entire subtree below that selected point.

Simply set the subtree to the new generated tree. Something like this:

```
public class Tree<E> {

    public void mutate() {
        Tree tree = this.getRandomSubtree();
        tree.replace(NEW_RANDOM_TREE);
    }

    public void replace(Tree<E> newTree) {
        if(this.isLeftChild()) this.getParent().setLeft(newTree);
        else                   this.getParent().setRight(newTree);
    }
    ...
}
```

The `getRandomSubtree()` method returns a random point in the tree.
The `getParent()` method of a tree returns the immediate parent node.

Note that you'll also have to check some cases where the random sub-tree returned is the root itself.

Answer (score 1):

1. Randomly select a point:
   [Select a Node at Random from Unbalanced Binary Tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20163414/select-a-node-at-random-from-unbalanced-binary-tree)
2. Remove subtree from selected node is not necessary, just get the depth of the selected subtree, and hold reference to it. http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/get-level-of-a-node-in-a-binary-tree/
3. Use your "full" method to generate a new random subtree with saved depth of old subtree and assign this subtree to your saved reference of old subtree, so the old subtree is killed by garbage collector.